# 301 редирект в Yi2

Tags: yii2

Подскажите, как в контролере настроить 301 редирект для страниц с динамическим адресом url .

То есть имеется url http://mysite.ru/product/samovar

Концовка урла формируется из базы данных, если я ее хочу поменять в базе данных, то как настроить переадресацию в коде?

Суть в том что не хочу делать редирект через htaccess так как возможно часто придется менять адрес страниц (сайт для тестов сео методов).

Не судите строго, я новичок в теме)

Answer (score 0):

можно в урл добавить id. 
И тогда при редактировании урлов ключ по id будет неизменным и можно сверять совпадает ли текущий с правильным и редиректить.
http://mysite.ru/product/samovar-12345

http://mysite.ru/product/starisamovar-12345

делать это можно через yii\web\UrlRule

Answer (score 0):

В голову приходит 2 варианта.

1. Если у товара имеется идентификатор, можно сформировать ссылку следующим образом http://mysite.ru/product/{id}/samovar. Настроить yii\web\UrlRule так, что нам нужна страница по адресу http://mysite.ru/product/{id} все остальное по большому счету не нужно. В этом случаи slug товара большую роль не играет. Мы получаем идентификатор из url, ищем товар, проверяем, что slug товара изменился и делаем 301 редирект, к примеру на http://mysite.ru/product/{id}/chajnik. Если slug товара не изменился, отдаем страницу.
2. Держать таблицу редиректов. При смене slug товара в таблицу заносим с какого на какой url сделать редирект. В этом случаи придется следить за таблицей, чтоб не получилось циклических редиректов.